# How to route all path to a single ServerResource with Restlet

Tags: java, restlet, restlet-2.0

This code is a very basic Restlet app:

```
public class FirstStepsApplication extends Application {
  private static final String ROOT_URI = "/";
  @Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach(ROOT_URI, RootServerResource.class);
    return router;
  }
}
```

How can I route not just root "`/`" into the `RootServerResource` but also all "`/*`" path? Is this a limitation of restlet or this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  router.attachDefault(RootServerResource.class);
```